# How can I parse output of Busybox's gzip?

Tags: gzip, busybox

I want to use gzip from Busybox v1.20.2 to extract a .tar.gz file to standard output then read it into my app and parse it. But the .tar.gz contains multiple files, some in subdirectories. I can see the output contains the filenames and the contents of those files interspersed with lots of 0's but I'm not sure what the format is.

I'm going to be using C++ and Qt if anyone has example code.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use Karchive? Anyway, you need to show the code and exact output you have.

Comment: Because it's an embedded device and I have limited space. What code am I supposed to show? I haven't written any yet.

Comment: How is Karchive relevant to limited space? Either way, you are supposed to write some code before asking.

Comment: "Not all questions benefit from including code" http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In other words, this is not a free code writing service. People are happy to help with existing code, but will not write code for you from scratch for such a broad/unclear topic.

Comment: I never asked for anyone to write my code, I'm asking about the output format of gzip.

Comment: It unclear what you are asking. I cannot find a single question in the body. What does it mean "How can I parse output of Busybox's gzip?"? Parse to do what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you have to go parsing a whole tar archive but you can just use `tar` to extract a specific file to `stdout` with `-O`. Example:

```
busybox tar -xOf /somewhere/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz zlib-1.2.8/zlib.h
```

Comment: Also, C++/Qt solutions were wanted.

Comment: @FinalContest C++/Qt solutions were wanted yet he was wanting to use a CLI tool like gzip. Looks like you made a good move giving a negative for an unwarranted assumption.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Then don't make a reply at all.

Comment: It is amusing how you post something that does not make any sense to me, and then you tell others not to post rather than clarifying yourself.

Comment: Why are you the OP? Who do you think you are? Well it's probably because others can comprehend things easier than you. You shouldn't think highly of your self.

Comment: `I'm going to be using C++ and Qt if anyone has example code.` -> why do you just not delete your irrelevant answer and feel shame? You clearly do not care what the OP wants, so why do you even "answer"?

Comment: `I want to use gzip from Busybox v1.20.2 to extract a .tar.gz file to standard output ` -> Still haven't got a clue? Then shut up already.

Comment: Wow do we even always have to confirm what the OP really wants over what he could possibly really need before making an answer? Looks like you're getting quite serious just for that.